# How to copy comment with tagged name in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I have posted a long comment with lots of my Facebook friends tagged within the text.

Now I want to copy the same comment onto another post - the pasted content removed all of the tags I made.

How can I keep tagged names?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Not to mention that clipboard is dependent on OS and device, this just isn't a feature of Facebook. You will only be able to pull the text no additional data.